# Sum of Converging sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm given this sequence where it goes:

$$ 1,\; \frac1a,\; \frac1{a(a+b)},\; \frac1{a^2(a+b)},\; \frac1{a^2(a+b)^2}, \frac1{a^3(a+b)^2}, \dotsc $$

where $a$ and $b$ are any positive integers

How would I go in finding the sum as there is no common ratio??

Comment: I think if you look at even and odd terms you'll find you can decompose your sum into two sums that are of a more standard form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your series looks like this:

$$ 1 + \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{a(a+b)} + \frac{1}{a^2 (a+b)} + \frac{1}{a^2 (a+b)^2} + \ldots$$

Notice that the terms in this series don't have a common ratio, but *every other term* has a common ratio. Given that this series is converging (absolutely), we can rewrite:

$$ 1 + \frac{1}{a(a+b)} + \frac{1}{a^2 (a+b)^2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{a^2(a+b)} + \frac{1}{a^3(a+b)^2} + \ldots$$

so we really get two geometric series added together:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^i (a+b)^i} + \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{a} \right) \frac{1}{a^i (a+b)^i}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the even and odd terms, you get two geometric sequences. So decompose, sum, and then put back together.